# Get git tag of checked out revision?

Tags: git, tags

I'm doing

```
$ git tag

current
tag_example_to_test_task

$ git checkout tag_example_to_test_task

...

HEAD is now at 75fdde3... commit comment text example

 $ git name-rev --name-only --tags HEAD

current

$ git describe --exact-match --tags

current
```

I need to end execution sequence with some command like this:

```
$ git "some command here"

tag_example_to_test_task
```

How to do that? How to get tag name of current checked out tag?

Comment: do you want to list all tags ?   git tag -l

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think

```
git log -n 1 --pretty=format:'%d'
```

should do the trick.

However, it'll show you names of all branches and tags your current revision has. I don't think it's possible to get just the single tag that have been used to check out the revision.

Answer (score 1):

To find what got you your current commit, you can use

```
git reflog | sed q
```

To hunt up your last checkout:

```
git reflog | sed '/ checkout: /! d; q'
```

That'll get you something like

```
b836444 HEAD@{7}: checkout: moving from AMFD to testing
```

showing that you've added seven commits since doing `git checkout testing`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
git tag --points-at=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
```

`git rev-parse HEAD` will get the SHA256 of the current HEAD. If this commit happens to be tagged, this will be replied. If the current HEAD is not tagged, the result is empty.

Comment: Your answer doesn't explain what happens when there're 2 tags on a single commit which is what the question is about.

Answer (score -1):

If you want the current version details, use `git describe`. It will tell you the last tag and the number of commits after that one. Human readable, not for program consumption really.

Answer (score -1):

this outputs just the tag of the latest commit.

```
# git log | head -1
commit 507e0647efd7e49aee53b14da970a7c2bf24555b
```