# Get git current branch/tag name

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, git-checkout

How can I get the current branch or tag name for my working copy?  I have seen references that indicate `rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` will give branch name, but this doesn't work if the checkout is of a tag, in which case it just returns 'HEAD'. I need to somehow get the tag name of these revisions.

To be clear, I want one of two possible names:

1. If the current checkout is the HEAD of a branch, I want the branch name
2. If it is a detached HEAD, I want the tag name (on the assumption there is a tag)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get git tag of checked out revision?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15703253/get-git-tag-of-checked-out-revision)

Comment: @FelixKling, the issue is really about getting a unified result. If you happen to check out a branch that has a tag the other method just gives the tag. So the question includes how to determine if indeed it is a detached HEAD/tag revision.

Comment: what about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404796/how-to-get-the-latest-tag-name-in-current-branch-in-git

Answer (score 80):

I think you want this:

```
git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD || git describe --tags --exact-match
```

That will output the value of HEAD, if it's not detached, or emit the tag name, if it's an exact match.  It'll show you an error otherwise.

Answer (score 27):

This command can print name in this priority: `tag` > `branch` > `commit`

```
git describe --tags --exact-match 2> /dev/null \
  || git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD \
  || git rev-parse --short HEAD
```

Comment: If a branch points to a tag and you do `git checkout branch` this command will return the tag. I think the correct order is `branch` -> `tag` as in the answer from @John Szakmeister which works fine in both cases (checking out branches and tags).

Answer (score 9):

This command can print name in this priority: `branch` > `tag` > `commit id`

```
git symbolic-ref --short -q HEAD \
  || git describe --tags --exact-match 2> /dev/null \
  || git rev-parse --short HEAD
```

Merged @xiaohui-zhang's answer and @thisismydesign's comment.  I keep coming back to this question every few months, and this is the answer I end up with, so I thought I'd post it.

Comment: I'm trying to work out under what circumstances this would return the tag name. I mean isnt every tag simply a tag on some branch (be it master or any other branch). This git command will always return the branch first, so why would it ever return the tag?

Comment: Branches refer to commits, and tags refer to commits.  If a branch and a tag both refer to the currently-checked-out commit, then this will return the branch.  If the currently-checked out commit has a tag, but no branch, this will return the tag.  If the currently-checked-out commit has no branch or tag, then this will return the commit ID.