# How to get the current checked out Git branch name through pygit2?

Tags: python, git, pygit2

This question should be related to:

- [How to get the current branch name in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245570/how-to-get-current-branch-name-in-git)
- [Get git current branch/tag name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18659425/get-git-current-branch-tag-name)
- [How to get the name of the current git branch into a variable in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111042/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-current-git-branch-into-a-variable-in-a-shell-script)
- [How to programmatically determine the current checked out Git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593051/how-to-programmatically-determine-the-current-checked-out-git-branch)

But I am wondering how to do that through [pygit2](http://www.pygit2.org/)?

Comment: http://www.pygit2.org/references.html#the-head - `repo.head` didn't do what you wanted?

Comment: Would you mind posting it as an answer? I believe that could also help others then :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From 
[PyGit Documentation](http://pygit2.org/references.html#the-head)

Either of these should work

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from pygit2 import Repository

repo = Repository('/path/to/your/git/repo')

# option 1
head = repo.head
print("Head is " + head.name)

# option 2
head = repo.lookup_reference('HEAD').resolve()
print("Head is " + head.name)
```

You'll get the full name including /refs/heads/.  If you don't want that strip it out or use shorthand instead of name.

```
./pygit_test.py  
Head is refs/heads/master 
Head is refs/heads/master
```

Comment: What is `repo` here?

Comment: @BorhanKazimipour it's the reference to the repo you are working on repo = Repository('path/to/git_repo')

Answer (score 47):

To get the conventional "shorthand" name:

```
from pygit2 import Repository

Repository('.').head.shorthand  # 'master'
```

Answer (score 28):

In case you don't want to or can't use pygit2

May need to alter path - this assumes you are in the parent directory of `.git`

```
from pathlib import Path

def get_active_branch_name():

    head_dir = Path(".") / ".git" / "HEAD"
    with head_dir.open("r") as f: content = f.read().splitlines()

    for line in content:
        if line[0:4] == "ref:":
            return line.partition("refs/heads/")[2]
```

Comment: I love this as based on basic libraries!

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`GitPython`](https://pypi.org/project/GitPython/):

```
from git import Repo
local_repo = Repo(path=settings.BASE_DIR)
local_branch = local_repo.active_branch.name
```

Comment: I managed to do this with just `Repo().head.ref.name`. This returns jsut the name of the branch.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do the following:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(["git", "branch", "--show-current"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
branch_name, branch_error = process.communicate()
```

which will work regardless of file paths and does not an additional require a package.