# Discovering git branch from python script

Tags: python

I have a python script.
I need to access the name of the git branch from which I'm running the python script, through python, during runtime.
Is there a way to do this?

Edit:
os.system("git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD") outputs to the cli, I don't see how I would get access to it *from* python...

I would like to have sth like `git_branch = <python commands>`

Comment: `os.system('git branch')`

Comment: What about using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python) with the `git branch` command?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the current checked out Git branch name through pygit2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26134026/how-to-get-the-current-checked-out-git-branch-name-through-pygit2)

Comment: @rdas better to use `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`

Comment: https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython

Answer (score 0):

You could use [GitPython](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html), something like the following:

```
>>> import git
>>> import os
>>> git_branch = git.Repo(os.getcwd()).active_branch.name
>>> git_branch
'master'
```

Otherwise, as already pointed out by Yevhen Kuzmovych in the comments, you could use [PyGit](https://www.pygit2.org/index.html).