# Get currently checked out full reference name in Git

Tags: git

I need a command which returns the full reference name of my currently checked out revision. Or as close to this as possible. Big plus if git-only (for cross-platform purposes).

By "full reference name" I mean e.g. `refs/tags/my-tag`, `refs/heads/my-branch`.

Examples:

```
git checkout master
magic command
# => /refs/heads/master

git checkout v1.0.0
magic command
# => /refs/tags/v1.0.0

git checkout 86742545e8152a8fbf31eafa55eb573042f61f5d
magic command
# =>
```

Few points of reference:

- I actually don't think this is possible with 100% accuracy because (as I understand git) there's no difference between checking out a tag and a specific hash. I.e. `.git/HEAD` shows the hash in both cases.
- `git show-ref` shows all references and the corresponding commit hashes
- `git symbolic-ref HEAD` works for branches and with the `-q` option it doesn't fail if you're not on a branch
- `git describe --tags --exact-match` kind of works for tags, but you'd need to prefix it with `refs/tags` and get rid of stderr

Related:

- [Get git current branch/tag name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18659425/get-git-current-branch-tag-name)
- [How to get the latest tag name in current branch in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404796/how-to-get-the-latest-tag-name-in-current-branch-in-git)

All I could find seemed too complicated for what I'm looking for.

Comment: try `git branch --list`. it will give you the name of the currently checked out branch.

Comment: "I need a command which returns the full reference name of my currently checked out revision."  
  
The modern term for this is "xy problem": you're in some situation, you've imagined a method for dealing with that situation based on your understanding of it, and are asking for implementation help with a troublesome step in that method—without explaining either method or motive—when the real problem is you're trying an approach that's so far suboptimal there's simply no support for it.  Could you explain what prompts this attempt please?

Comment: @jthill thanks for the help & description, but my problem is wanting to do exactly what's described in the question. It's prompted by me wondering how to do it.

Comment: Well, I've had idle curiosity grab hold of me before too, but I try not to call that a "need" without making the humorous intent a little less implicit.

Comment: Fair enough, I suppose I'd like to know if there's a command which...

Answer (score 2):

You probably want `git describe`, perhaps with some flags and perhaps with some post-processing.  See details below.

---

I'm not entirely sure what actual problem you are trying to solve:

- The hash ID is the permanent name for *this* commit.  So just `git rev-parse HEAD` and you have it.
- The *current branch name* is what `git symbolic-ref HEAD` gets.  It produces an error if there is no current branch name, which is the case whenever you use `git checkout` to switch to a *detached HEAD*.  That includes:

  - checking out a non-branch name (e.g., a tag name or remote-tracking name),
  - using `--detach` with a branch name, and
  - using a raw hash ID (of course).

Note that a branch name stores one commit hash ID, except for the somewhat special case of being on an "unborn branch", in which case, the branch name doesn't exist, even though it is the current branch name.  This somewhat obnoxious state is necessary *because* a branch name *must* contain the hash ID of an existing commit, and in a new, totally-empty repository, there *is* no existing commit, yet you're started out on branch `master`.

If the problem you are trying to solve is: "Tell me what command the user typed in to *get* into the `HEAD` state I'm in now, whether that is detached or attached", *Git* does not save that for you.  The closest you get are entries in the `HEAD` reflog.  This reflog is not required to exist.  One other place to look is in history saved by the *shell* (command line interpreter): if that history exists, it probably contains the exact command the user entered, even if that command is an alias.

If the problem you are trying to solve is: "Provide a name useful to / readable by humans, that will (always | currently) identify this exact commit", there is no right answer, but the closest you can come is to make *your own new tag* for the current commit hash ID.  The *second*-closest you can come, which is pretty useful, is to use the output of `git describe` (which has lots of flags to tweak its output).  Note that using a branch name will only identify the same commit *until* the branch name moves on to identify some *other* commit, which happens regularly.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just wondering if this is possible. I'd use it for something like "tell me where the user expects to be now? - on a tag / branch / commit", so your first case. But the right answer is that it's not simply possible. `reflog` is great but makes things very complicated.

Comment: Well, that's what `git status` tries to do too. It would be nice if there were a plumbing equivalent of "obtain the thing that `git status` will say about the branch" (the first line info, `on branch foo` or `HEAD detached at/from ...`), but there isn't - but you can do `git status | head -1`, crude as that is.